# Only Show Content when Scrolled Above x on Screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a website for my new game, and I want to put a menu at the top--but I don't want the page contents to show behind it. I would use a simple div element, but I want the content to fade as it gets higher after point x on the screen.

Is there any code that could do this? I've seen it done before. Example follows.

```
This is the menu
This is where the page content starts fading

This is the rest of the page content
This is the footer
```

I've tried to do this by simply using a fixed div, but it is solid, and I want the text to fade.

Comment: There's multiple ways to do this.  Normally you should show what you've tried already - that's probably what the downvote is for - If your menu will always be the same, consider making a png image that has a fade on it and attach it to the menu so it covers your scrolling content

Comment: Please show what your previous attempts at doing this were. You can post some code of what you've tried so far, or perhaps link to some sites you've found. Try doing some research before asking your question here.

Comment: @ntgCleaner I'll try that, thanks! And the reason I didn't put any code is because all I could think of was a solid div, but that didn't fade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.
The idea would be to put a `div` underneath the menu and make it's background gradient from white at top to transparent at bottom. And no jQuery is needed for this.
Here is a sampe: http://jsfiddle.net/QL63w/1/

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking! Thanks!